# Images after javascript are showed with a delay and reordering

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I get the src code for image from PHP and after show at the HTML but the images are shown with a delay. How can I show the images all together without reordering after all loaded?
HTML

```
     <div id="keys"></div>
```

JS

```
function sendGETDataToServer() {
  // Set up our HTTP request
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  // Setup our listener to process completed requests
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    // Only run if the request is complete
    if (xhr.readyState !== 4) return;
    // Process our return data
    if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
      var JsonResponse = xhr.responseText;
      var response = JSON.parse(JsonResponse);
      console.log(response);
      if (response[0] == "200 OK") {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < response[1]; i++) {
          let img = document.createElement("img");
          img.src = response[2 + i].FilePath;
          img.setAttribute("style", "width:8%; padding-left:1em; float:left");

          $("#keys").append(img);
        }
      }
    } else {
      console.log("error", xhr);
    }
  };
  xhr.open("GET", "load.php");
  xhr.send();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should look like something like that

```
      if (response[0] == '200 OK') {
        var i;
        var nbLoaded = 0;
        var nbToLoad = 0;
        var pendingImages = [];
        for (i = 0; i < response[1]; i++) {
          nbToLoad++;
          let img = document.createElement('img');
          img.src = response[2 + i].FilePath;
          img.setAttribute('style', 'width:8%; padding-left:1em; float:left');
          img.onload = () => {
            nbLoaded++;
            if (nbLoaded === nbToLoad) {
              pendingImages.forEach((image) => {
                $('#keys').append(image);
              });
            }
          };
          pendingImages.push(img);
        }
      }
```

Comment: Can i display the contents of all the page after all image come ?

Comment: Technically, yes it could be possible by adding a CSS display:none to the body or the top most parent element on your page before loading your images and removing it when all images are loaded. 
But from an UX point of view, it's would be a bit weird, it would feel slow to see nothing. Instead, I would load the page but put a loading spinner or something while images are loading.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your problem: There isn't really one. There is not a way to know what order your images will arrive in, and you certainly cannot control the delay. What you can control is the order you show them in. The simplest way to do this is to wait until you have received all of your images, and while you are receiveing them, you store them in an array somewhere. After you receive the final image, you could simply order the array the way you want your images to be displayed, and run through it to actually put the images on the page. If you need any help with the specifics, please feel free to ask!

Comment: The other contibutor say something about event load. Do you know any examples of how can this be done with multiple images (around 40) ?